# Spring WebClient without the springboot-starter-web-flux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Mine is a Spring boot application, but doesnt uses any web-feature. It's just used as a command-line app that will be triggered by a CRON in a scheduled interval and then it performs the job and die (**is not ever running web app**)

In this Job, I would need to make a REST call and would need to use `WebClient` for the same. Below is my dependency i use to bring in the WebClient

> `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'`

But this dependency keeps my app running and doesnt allow the job to die once the job is done. I tried excluding netty from the above dependency, but that is resulting in the below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.

How to use `WebClient` and at the same time not to use any Web features ?

**Note:** I tried giving `spring.main.web-application-type=none` in my property file and it is helping me to exclude web-feature. But is that the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not the only way but I think it’s certainly the easiest.

You could manually configure the type of application context that’s used and exclude some auto-configuration classes, but setting the `web-application-type` property or configuring it programmatically on `SpringApplication` or `SpringApplicationBuilder` will achieve the same result with less code and configuration.